# Read .PDF/.TXT files in android

Tags: android

How to read pdf files which are stored in assets in  my android application

Comment: In what way do you want to "read" .pdfs? They are not plain text files.

Comment: Asset files can be accessed via "getContext().getAssets().open("file_name.txt")"

Comment: i want to read .pdf file from asset?

Answer (score 1):

For PDF's you will need a PDF library like PDFBox as neither Android or Java have native support for PDF's. You could have googled that.

http://pdfbox.apache.org/